# Configure Prettier so that it does not format JSX parts of JS file?

Tags: prettier

I would like to avoid Prettier formatting the JSX parts of my typescript files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to add the [`// prettier-ignore`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html), there are no options to disable it and there are no plans to add this support.